# Three20 & MonoTouch: TTTabStrip change color doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.ios, three20

I've created a new class that inherits from TTDefaultStyleSheet.

```
public class BlackStyleSheet : TTDefaultStyleSheet
{
    public BlackStyleSheet() : base()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BlackStyleSheet created.");
    }

    public override UIColor TabBarTintColor 
    {
        get
        {
        Console.WriteLine("BlackStyleSheet.TabBarTintColor returned.");
            return UIColor.Black;
        }
    }

    [Export ("tabTintColor")]
    public override UIColor TabTintColor 
    {
        get 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BlackStyleSheet.TabTintColor returned.");
            return UIColor.Black;
        }
    }
}
```

And I set this custom style sheet as the default in my FinishedLaunching method.

```
public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application)
{
    Three20.TTStyleSheet.GlobalStyleSheet = new BlackStyleSheet();
    Three20.TTDefaultStyleSheet.GlobalStyleSheet = new BlackStyleSheet();
    Console.WriteLine("Three20 style sheet set.");
}
```

Then, I create the actual TTTabStrip and TTTabItem elements within my own custom UIViewController's ViewDidLoad() method. *The TTTabItem objects are declared at the class level instead of the method level.*

```
tab1 = new TTTabItem("1");
tab2 = new TTTabItem("2");
tab3 = new TTTabItem("3");
TabStrip = new TTTabStrip();
TabStrip.Frame = new RectangleF(0,0,View.Frame.Width, 44);
TabStrip.TabItems = NSArray.FromNSObjects(tab1,tab2,tab3);
TabStrip.SelectedTabIndex = 0;
View.AddSubview(TabStrip);
```

When the TTDefaultStyleSheet.GlobalStyleSheet property is set to the new custom stylesheet, the app crashes. When this property setting is removed, the app runs perfectly, but the tab strip remains grey.

In all forums I've read (none seem to be MonoTouch-specific), they all indicate that creating your own stylesheet, then setting it to the global stylesheet is the way to go. But this doesn't seem to work for me with MonoTouch.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you,

John K.

Comment: I just ran into this problem myself, did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example in XCode with Objective-C and I can confirm that this this approach does work.  I also tried for myself with MonoTouch and saw the same results you report.

I have found several problems in the Three20 binding code in the past that seem to cause aborts like this.  You can try and fix up the existing binding code or create only the bindings you need from Three20 manually.

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_types

Comment: I also see the same crash, hopefully someone will post here if it is resolved.